# Conditions if Cookie exists doesn't work (Js, Html)

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

i've made a closable banner with Html, CSS and JS . 
Everything works fine but i want to make it disappear once the user hit the Close Button and never be shown again ( while changing from Site to another or after refreshing the browser ) 
i've stored a cookie , but my code to do changes if the cookie exists doesn't work

what i'm doing wrong?

```js
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  });
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var x = getCookie("clicklink");
  if (x == null) {
    document.getElementById("close").style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("close").style.display = 'none';

  }
}
```

```css
.closable {
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  right: 0%;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.close:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="close" class="closable" onload="checkCookie()">
  <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></p>
  <p style="text-align: center">
    s simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
  <span class="close" id="clink" onclick="setCookie('clicklink', 'yes', 7)">
        &times;
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Use localStorage instead and divs do not have onload. Only BODY, IMG and iFrames have

Comment: `span` elements are not designed to be clicked on, they don't appear in the focus order and are not announced as being interactive by screen readers. If you want something to be clicked on to run some JS then use a `button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if `x === null` but your getCookie function returns an empty string. Therefore your condition is never met.

Answer (score 2):

Only the `body` element has an `onload` attribute (which refers to the entire document loading). `div` elements don't load anything so don't. Consequently, the `checkCookie` function is never called.

A [validator](https://validator.nu/) would have highlighted this error.

Answer (score 1):

if `x = ""`, `x==null` will not return `true`.

You should return `null` if no cookie is present.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the already mentioned "No onload on divs" you should not write your own cookie script

I would use localStorage instead of cookies

I also delegate from a container

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // let divs = localStorage.getItem("divs"); // uncomment on your server
  divs = {"close1": {"closed": true}};        // remove when tested
  // divs = divs ? JSON.parse(divs) : {};      // uncomment on your server
  
  [...document.querySelectorAll("div.closable")].forEach(div => {
    const id = div.id;
    // you could use classList.toggle here instead of style.display
    if (divs[id] && divs[id].closed === true) div.style.display = "none";
  })
  
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) { // delegation
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("close")) {
      const parentDiv = tgt.closest("div.closable"); // find the parent 
      divs[parentDiv.id] = { "closed" : true };
      // localStorage.setItem("divs",JSON.stringify(divs)); // uncomment on server
      parentDiv.style.display = "none";
      console.log(divs)
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.closable {
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  right: 0%;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.close:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="close1" class="closable">
    <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum 1</strong></p>
    <p style="text-align: center">
      s simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </p>
    <button class="close">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="close2" class="closable">
    <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum 2</strong></p>
    <p style="text-align: center">
      s simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </p>
    <button class="close">&times;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```